# Fallback image file for includegraphics

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

My question is something I feel should be relatively easy to resolve, but I cannot find any references online on how to do it. The basic premise of my situation is as follows:

I have a number of image files for a project I am working on which are based on data that occasionally changes. When this data changes, I run a Python script that regenerates the data at various resolutions, starting with the least detailed versions so that I have a quick draft of what the new graphics will look like and then moving up through the resolutions. Creating a final version can take up to an hour, and I'd rather not have to wait that long for the image referenced in my code to update.

As such, I was wondering if it is possible to set up my `\includegraphics` command to allow a sequence of fallback images, such that when I regenerate the graphics I delete the old versions and allow new ones with the same filenames to show up as they are generated, so that any existing file with that name is the most current version, without raising nonexistent-file errors in the typesetting process.

A basic idea of what I am aiming for, in TeX-ish pseudocode, is

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
...stuff...
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics{if file1.pdf exists: file1.pdf
                  elif file2.pdf exists: file2.pdf
                  elif file3.pdf exists: file3.pdf
                  else: file4.pdf}

\end{center}
...more stuff...
\end{document}
```

I am using pdfLaTeX at the moment, so I would prefer raw-TeX or LaTex answers if possible, although I could probably make XeTeX/LuaLaTex/ConTeXt/etc. solutions work if need be.

Comment: Document class? Are you committed to this syntax? Are you really producing DVI so using LaTeX as opposed to pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @cfr Does my edit answer your questions?

Comment: Thanks, mostly it does. It would be safer to define a new command rather than redefining `\includegraphics`. That's why I asked about the syntax. Or you could put something before the `\includegraphics`, probably, but I'd just define a new command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following does mostly what you want, I think, but with a different command. If you really want to you can `\RenewDocumentCommand \includegraphics ...` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand \includegraphicslist ...` but I would not recommend doing so. Redefining `\includegraphics` will almost certainly have unwanted side-effects. Worse, it may not cause those side-effects until later, by which time you will have forgotten you redefined it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713985/
\usepackage{graphicx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__graphicslist_filelist_seq
\tl_new:N \l__graphicslist_file_tl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \graphicslist_includegraphics:nn
{
  \includegraphics [ #1 ] { #2 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \graphicslist_includegraphics:nn { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \graphicslist_includegraphicslist:nn
{
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__graphicslist_filelist_seq { #2 }
  \seq_get_left:NN \l__graphicslist_filelist_seq \l__graphicslist_file_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__graphicslist_filelist_seq
  {
    \file_if_exist:nT { ##1 }
    {
      \seq_map_break:n {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__graphicslist_file_tl { ##1 }
      }
    }
  }
  \graphicslist_includegraphics:nV { #1 } \l__graphicslist_file_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand \includegraphicslist { O {} m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \graphicslist_includegraphicslist:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\includegraphicslist[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf,example-image-b.pdf}
\includegraphicslist[scale=.5]{example-image-x.pdf,example-image-a.pdf,example-image-b.pdf}
\includegraphicslist[width=.2\textwidth,height=.5\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a.pdf,example-image-x.pdf}
\end{document}
```

`\includegraphicslist[]{}` is just like `\includegraphics[]{}` except that the second argument may take a comma-separated list of file names and, whether it does so or not, the filename extension is mandatory. It would be possible to eliminate this requirement, but it is probably not worth the additional work.

If a list of file names is given, they should be listed in descending order of priority. If the first exists, all later names are ignored; likewise with the second and so forth.

The result of compiling the above is a line of `example-image-a`s in different sizes. Given the result is utterly uninteresting and Okular/KDE has a new bug rendering any image I paste of very poor quality, I will refrain from inflicting an image on you at this time.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to do exactly what I want. Indeed, I was suspecting I would need a new command, but I was hoping there was some secret setting that already existed in `\includegraphics` that would allow me to do this as a built-in feature.

Comment: @Mel If there's such a feature, I'm not aware of it. But I suppose that would be expected of a secret feature ;). If the files had the same name but different extensions, you could do it because `graphicx` is setup for that. But it only looks for one base name ....

Comment: @cfr  Just curious since the input is in the form of a clist already, why did you transfrom it to a seq?

Comment: @yannisl I believe sequences are quicker and I could tell you that, but an honest answer would be: because I knew the commands I needed existed for sequences and I would have had to remind myself for clists because I happen to have used the sequence ones more recently.